# View controller hierarchy initialization has changed in iOS5

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, ios5, uinavigationbar, presentmodalviewcontroller

Here is the problem.
I have the following view hierarchy which is pushed modally using a flip animation:

- BackViewController

  - UITabBarController

    - UINavigationController

      - ForecastListViewController

It looks like this:

[image]

Here is the sequence of calls during the flip in iOS 4.3:

1. **BackViewController viewDidLoad**
2. **ForecastListViewController viewDidLoad**
3. *BackViewController viewWillAppear*
4. *ForecastListViewController viewWillAppear*
5. BackViewController viewDidAppear
6. ForecastListViewController viewDidAppear

In iOS 5.0 the order is different (step 2 and 3 are switched):

1. **BackViewController viewDidLoad**
2. *BackViewController viewWillAppear*
3. **ForecastListViewController viewDidLoad**
4. *ForecastListViewController viewWillAppear*
5. BackViewController viewDidAppear
6. ForecastListViewController viewDidAppear

The problem is that now the top of the navigation bar appears 10 pixels under the bottom of the status bar during the flip animation, then snaps back to its expected position once the animation terminates.

I have tried changing the navigation bar frame in ForecastListViewController viewDidLoad method without success: nothing happens.

If I force a load of the ForecastListViewController so it occurs as as step 2 (by forcing a traversal of the hierarchy while investigating this issue) all is fine again. But I am looking for a good solution instead of this "hack".

Any one with this problem?
Any clue or pointer?
I am at a loss on how to solve this elegantly